# Wordpress Deleted Pages still showing when I type in the URL

Tags: wordpress

I recently deleted the shop on my website and all pages connected to the shop, but when I type the URL of those pages they are still existing. The theme of my website is Woodmart

Examples of pages that still exist:  "shop/", "shop/about-us", "shop/cart"...

Please Help

Comment: and pages are permanently deleted so when I go on the page with URL I cant edit them

Comment: What plugins have you installed on your site? Do you have Woocommerce and/or WPML ?

Comment: I only have Woocommerce install

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a post or page in WP, it is "moved to the trash", i.e. it still exists. So while you are logged in, you will still be able to call them - visitors without login should not be able to see them. But you can empty the trash (from the backend list view of posts or pages) to delete them completely.

If it's still possible to view them afterwards, they are obviously cashed in the browser or on the (proxy?) server.

Comment: how can I delete it from the server ?

Answer (score 0):

1-Clear your cache

2-Can Delete pages permanently from database

3-Empty the cache

Comment: I tried all of that but the page is still visible and I cant edit it anymore. :/